# Combining two Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two objects

```
var data = {property: [
  {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
  {id: "2", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"},
  {id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action"},
  {id: "4", name: "Ordinary People", type: "drama"},
  {id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama"},
  {id: "6", name: "Toy Story", type: "children"}
]};
```

and

```
var data = {property: [
  {id: "7", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
  {id: "8", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"}
]};
```

Can I use jquery or javascript to combine the two as follows

```
var data = {property: [
  {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
  {id: "2", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"},
  {id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action"},
  {id: "4", name: "Ordinary People", type: "drama"},
  {id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama"},
  {id: "6", name: "Toy Story", type: "children"},
  {id: "7", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
  {id: "8", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"}
]};
```

I've tried to use the push function but with no luck

Comment: You have no JSON there at all. You have JavaScript objects.

Comment: … and it is the arrays you are trying to combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var data = {property: []}

var data2 = {property: []}

data.property =data.property.concat(data2.property);
```

Using `concat` function of the Array you can join them.

Answer (score 0):

concat is one solution, but [underscore.js' union](http://underscorejs.org/#union) will take care of any duplicates as well.

```
var data3 = _.union(data.property, data2.property)
```